# Random double loop in Python

Tags: python

I would like to create a random double loop in Python.

For example, for `(N,N)=(2,2)` the program should give:

```
0 1
0 0
1 1
1 0
```

Or another example

```
0 0
1 1
1 0
0 1
```

So far, I have done this:

```
r1 = list(range(2))
r2 = list(range(2))
random.shuffle(r1)
random.shuffle(r2)
for i in r1:
    for j in r2:
        # Do something with i
```

This, however, does not give the desired result, because I want i's to be shuffled too and not give for example all `(1,x)` sequentially. Any ideas?

Comment: Create all the outputs first and then shuffle

Answer (score 5):

Shuffle the product of the ranges, not each individual range.

```
import itertools


pairs = list(itertools.product(r1, r2))  # [(i,j) for i in r1 for j in r2]
random.shuffle(pairs)

for i, j in pairs:
    ...
```